# Are the following terms correct: "internal worker", "external worker"?

Tags: word-usage

I am searching for two opposing terms:

How to call a person who is employed by a company?

How to call a person who is not employed directly be a company, but cooperates with this company, for example, a freelancer?

Would these terms "internal worker" and "external worker" be appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

> How to call a person who is employed by a company?

*Answer*: You can call them ***employees*** of the organization

*[employee](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/employee)*

> (noun) a person working for another person or a business firm for pay.

[Dictionary.com]

---

> How to call a person who is not employed directly be a company, but cooperates with this company, for example, a freelancer?

*Answer*: You can refer to them as ***third party.*** However, I think the term ***freelancer*** conveys the intended meaning very well.

*[third party](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/third-party)*

> (adj.) Relating to a person or group besides the two primarily involved in a situation

[ODO]

In the IT industry, we often use the term ***third party vendors*** or ***third party auditors*** (besides internal and external) to refer to personnel  not directly employed by our company but use their services when appropriate.

Comment: The word *consultant* could be used depending on business.

Comment: Agreed with @Ranthony, and add "contractor" to the list.

Answer (score 1):

The general official term , in USA and Canada is

> **Independent contractors**

from the point of view of the person who pays for their service:

> People such as doctors, dentists, veterinarians, lawyers, accountants,
>   contractors, subcontractors, public stenographers, or auctioneers who
>   are in an independent trade, business, or profession in which they
>   offer their services to the general public are generally **independent
>   contractors.**

and

> **Self-employed**

from the point of view of the person paid.

> If you are an independent contractor, you are **self-employed**.
>
> Whether these people are **independent
>   contractors or employees** depends on the facts in each case. The
>   general rule is that an individual is an independent contractor if the
>   payer has the right to control or direct only the result of the work
>   and not what will be done and how it will be done.

IRS: https://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Independent-Contractor-Defined

Canada: http://sbinfocanada.about.com/od/taxinfo/a/contractor1.htm

Then depending of the field, you could use a more precise word, such as sub-contractor (building), consultant (I.T), guest (academy: guest speaker, guest lecturer) etc.